# Generic return type for a public method

Tags: java

I have a simple AVL tree implementation with a public method `getMax()` like so:

```
public class AVLTree <Data extends Comparable<Data>> {
    public AVLTree() {
        this.root = null;
    } 

    public Data getMax() {
        return getMaxNode(root).data;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I form the tree using `Integer` inputs, I cannot use the `getMax()` method without casting the result to `Integer`, which seems strange to me. Here's an example:

```
AVLTree avltree = new AVLTree();
avltree.insert(10);   

Integer i = (Integer)avltree.getMax(); <-- Here        

System.out.println(avltree.getMax().getClass()); // Test
```

If I delete `(Integer)`, the IDE says "incompatible types: Comparable cannot be converted to Integer". What's strange is that the output for `getClass()` is `class java.lang.Integer`. So my question is: why do I have to cast the output to `Integer` in this case when the return type seems to be an `Integer`?

Comment: AVLTree<Integer>  avltree = new AVLTree<Integer>();
avltree.getMax(); You have created generic class correctly but the object declaration that you did is not generic and hence you had to type cast

Comment: @ManjunathAnand Thanks! I just read that in the question linked by Sotirios but its good to get a confirmation.